# Qgis 3.16.3 - tk package, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, tkinter

I am developing a plugin that uses tk package. When I tried to import tk I got an error: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'**. I tried to reinstall tk but it didn't work. I would say that when i used local python tk package works.

Comment: Try "import tkinter", without underline. But @Dror Bogin is right, you had better to use Qt in your plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QGIS uses PyQt for ui, and it doesn't come with a preinstalled Tkinter python package.
I would recommend you either include the relevant package code with your plugin (if the license allows for that),
or use PyQt to build your interface.

I would recommend learning PyQt and using the included Qt Designer as instructed [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins/plugins.html) in the pyqgis developer cookbook.